# Setting up a web server on a VM

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, oracle

*Running: Windows Vista Ultimate x64*

I'm a web developer, using mainly PHP and MySQL, and I've decided that using XAMPP doesn't cut it any more (I want to play with the Oracle database system, and other stuff).

Yesterday I installed 2GB of RAM into my machine, for a total of 4GB. So I thought about setting up a Virtual machine that will act as a server for processing the PHP code.

I have absolutely no experience in managing a server, but I've tried many tutorials to set up one in CentOS and Ubuntu with no luck.

Here I am, asking you guys:

**Can anybody help me or point me to a tested guide to set up a webserver, step by step?**

I know my way around Linux so I'm not a total newbie.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great success with [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/products/server/downloads-all).  Zend Server CE ships with the major components PHP 5, MySQL 5, and Apache 2.2 all pre-configured to communicate properly, easily handling the "AMP" part of your LAMP setup.  As the starting point I wish Zend had shipped years ago, I can't recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 2):

once you install CentOS, do followings

yum install httpd
yum install php
yum install mysql-server
yum install php-mysql

this is for your httpd & mysql & php, oracle you may need to download from their site directly and use their documentations on how to install it on your CentOS

Comment: I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Indeed worked :)

One more thing: it only has PHP 5.1.6.

When I download 5.3 and compile from source, how do I tell Apache to use the new module and not the old one?

Comment: i think when you do make install it copy module inside of modules directory and overwrite the older one...

Answer (score 1):

There are some awesome [tutorials/articles](http://articles.slicehost.com) over at Slicehost. They are to the point and cover a wide range of server related set ups.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable new repositories in case you will want to install higher version of php, I'd recommend to enable the remy and rpmforge repositories.

Compiling from source code might be a problem in the future since you won't be able to upgrade it easily with "yum upgrade"

Answer (score 0):

Here's [my favorite.](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-9.04-ispconfig-2)

It does a walkthrough of more stuff than just Apache, so pick and choose what you think you need. GREAT setup for web hosting. I've tested this tutorial with previous versions, and they work great.

Google search: perfect ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

I like ["The Perfect Server" (CentOS)](http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.1-server-lamp-email-dns-ftp-ispconfig).